# How does one create a bootable SD?

Tags: 12.04, boot, sd-card

I am going to be replacing ubuntu 11.10 with 12.04. Can I create a bootable MicroSD, or do I have to create the image on a CD?

Comment: This should still work: http://www.ehow.com/way_5622200_ways-boot-sd-card-linux.html ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the link in comment](http://www.ehow.com/way_5622200_ways-boot-sd-card-linux.html):

> Within Ubuntu
>
> If you're already using Ubuntu on a computer, you can already turn an Ubuntu ISO file into a bootable SD card. Simply click "System," then "Administration," then "USB Startup Disk Creator." You'll be presented with a Windows asking for two things: the location of the ISO file and the disk you would like to overwrite. Note that this method completely overwrites a given SD card, so be sure to do this only with an empty card (or a full one with files you don't mind losing).

So if you still have the ISO you are set to go. Otherwise download it first.

The only difference with that link: now you open dash and search for `USB` or `Startup disc creator`.